# Error when update/add product

Tags: product, magento2.3, admin, product-review, product-tab

In admin when i click on product edit get a error

[2021-04-06 13:14:56] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'product.reviews' element cannot be added as child to 'product_tabs', because the latter doesn't exist [] []

Why this error is occured? Please help me

Comment: This debug log refers to a frontend layout warning, it has nothing to do with admin / product editing. Please provide more information as to what exactly happens when you try to edit the product edit in admin

Answer (score 0):

did you find a solution to this problem ?
I have a similar error:
main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'product.reviews' element cannot be added as child to 'product_tabs', because the latter doesn't exist []

Thank you

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/195599)